# Remote lock or wipe of a lost or stolen chromebook?

Tags: chromebook, anti-theft

Is it possible to remote wipe or remote lock a lost chromebook? The procedure is spottily documented, but seems to vary based on account type:

- Chromebook, consumer gmail account
- Chromebook, enterprise account
- Chromebook enabled for android app store (consumer gmail account)

Is it possible to remote wipe a chromebook by serial number, rendering it less useful to a thief?  I tried remote wipe of an app store chromebook, but was offered only the ability to expire the active session.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to protect your data regardless of account type is to enable "Show lock screen when waking from sleep" under Screen Lock in Settings.  Once the Chromebook's lid is closed, you data is protected and encrypted on disk until unlocked by password or PIN so a remote wipe is not necessary.

To lessen the inconvenience of this setup, the Chromebook can be unlocked with just a mouse click when a designated Android phone is present:
https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/6070209?hl=en